# Linq updating XML-document

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm just creating an app that stores the settings in a xml file.
If I now want to save a new parameter, I need to check if that parameter already exists and update it or add it to the document.

Actually I solve it this way:

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(appDataFolder + @"\settings.xml");
foreach(XElement xElement in xDocument.Descendants("Settings"))
{
    if(xElement.Element("projectFile") != null)
        xElement.Element("projectFile").Value = projectFile;
    else
        xElement.Add(new XElement("projectFolder", projectFile));

    if (xElement.Element("projectFolder") != null)
        xElement.Element("projectFolder").Value = projectFolder;
    else
        xElement.Add(new XElement("projectFolder", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments)));

        }
    xDocument.Save(appDataFolder + @"\settings.xml");
```

This is the actual settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--System-Settings-->
<Settings version="1.0.0.0">
  <projectFile>C:\Users\Public\Documents\project.prj</projectFile>
  <projectFolder>C:\Users\Public\Documents</projectFolder>
</Settings>
```

Isn't there a more handy way that automatically adds an element, if it doesn't exist?

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but maybe you should consider using [XmlConfigurationProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.xml.xmlconfigurationprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) for storing your app settings? It's more convenient to use than manually reading an XML file.

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestions. Sure this is a possible way but I need to interact with xml files for other jobs in that app too, so also for that, it is useful to get an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Xml.Linq.XElement` actually has a method that does exactly that, namely [`SetElementValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.setelementvalue?view=netframework-4.8).

It takes an `XName` and the desired content, adding or updating according to your intuition.

Both

```
var xml = XElement.Parse("<outer></outer>");
xml.SetElementValue("inner", 2);
```

and

```
var xml = XElement.Parse("<outer><inner>1</inner></outer>");
xml.SetElementValue("inner", 2);
```

result in

```
<outer><inner>2</inner></outer>
```

As we can see from the [remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.setelementvalue?view=netframework-4.8#remarks), it was designed with your use case in mind.

> This method is designed to make it easy to maintain a list of
>   name/value pairs as a set of children elements. When maintaining the
>   list, you need to add pairs, modify pairs, or delete pairs. If you
>   call this method passing a name that does not exist as a child
>   element, this method creates a child element for you. If you call this
>   method passing the name of an existing child element, this method
>   modifies the value of the child element to the value that you specify.
>   If you pass null for value, this method removes the child element.

Comment: Wow really great. Thank you! But one question, what does the "y" in the second example `xml.SetElementValue("y",2);` do?

Comment: @Telefisch it was a leftover from when I renamed my test code. fixed.